# Doubly Linked List in javascript

Tags: javascript, data-structures, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I was building linked list in javascript.
I dont understand one part.

```js
function Node(element) {
 this.element = element;
 this.next = null;
 this.previous = null;
}

function LList() {
 this.head = new Node("head");
 
 this.find = find;
 this.findLast = findLast;

 this.remove = remove;
 this.insert = insert;
 this.display = display;
 this.dispReverse = dispReverse;
  
}

function find(item) {
 var currNode = this.head;
 while(currNode.element != item) {
  currNode = currNode.next;
 }

 return currNode;
}


function display(list) {
 var currNode = this.head.next;
 while (currNode != null) {
  console.log(currNode.element);
  currNode = currNode.next;
 }
}


function insert(newElement, item) {
 var newNode = new Node(newElement);
 var current = this.find(item);
 newNode.next = current.next;
 newNode.previous = current;
 current.next = newNode;


 // Why I dont need this part?
    // Since new node got inserted, on my thoughts,
    // the next node of the current node should point the new node as a previous one
    // current.next.previous = newNode;
 
}

function remove(item) {
 var currNode = this.find(item);
 if (currNode.next != null) {
  currNode.previous.next = currNode.next;
  currNode.next.previous = currNode.previous;
  currNode.next = null;
  currNode.previous = null;
 }
}

function findLast() {
 var currNode = this.head;
 while (currNode.next != null) {
  currNode = currNode.next;
 }

 return currNode;
}

function dispReverse() {

 var currNode = this.head;
 currNode = this.findLast();

 while(currNode.previous != null) {
  console.log(currNode.element);
  currNode = currNode.previous;
 }
}

var cities = new LList(); 
cities.insert("Conway", "head"); 
cities.insert("Russellville", "Conway"); 
cities.insert("Carlisle", "Russellville"); 
cities.insert("Alma", "Carlisle"); 
cities.display();

cities.remove("Carlisle");
cities.display();
cities.dispReverse();


/*
Output should look like this: 

Conway
Russellville
Carlisle
Alma

Conway
Russellville
Alma

Alma
Russellville
Conway
*/
```

Problem is the insert function!

Let's say if I have A B C node already.

And I want to insert K after B.


Currently, the next and previous of B are C and A for each.

The previous element of C is B.

Once I put K after B,

A B K C

(1) the next element of K will be C

(2) the previous element of K will be B.

(3) The next element of B is K

(4) previous element of C is K.


On the code I wrote in Insert function, each line of the codes below should process the upper statements.

(1) newNode.next = current.next;

(2) newNode.previous = current;

(3) current.next = newNode;

(4) current.next.previous = newNode;


But when I run this whole code including (4), error has occurred.

I don understand why...

Without the (4) line of codes, it works.


Is there anyone who can help me understand this?

Comment: Do you want to tell us what the error is?

Comment: Did you try to debug via some console.log ? Can you provide us the exact error ? Sounds like a reference problem to me

Comment: @FelixKling  Oh I think I didnt explain clearly. Inside the insert function there is comment like this. // current.next.previous = newNode; I think this is a proper code to be included in the insert function but when I put that inside the function and run it, error happens!

Comment: @stephane-ruhlmann As I mentioned up there, the code above works just fine. What I wonder is I think [current.next.previous = newNode;] should be included inside the insert function. Now I made it as a comment with '//'. So it didn't make an error.

Comment: Ok I get it, still an object reference issue to me, see answer below

Comment: Again, you say "error happens" but you are not telling us *what* the error is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do step 4 before step 3:

```
current.next.previous = newNode
current.next = newNode
```

As it is, the reference of `current.next` (C) is being set to `newNode` (K) before you lookup the "old" `current.next`'s `previous` property ( `current.next.previous` when points to B). Your reference to the current node is changed as soon as you assign it a new value. This is why `current.next.previous` is actually returning `newNode.previous` instead of the node reference you expect.

Comment: THANKS!! It really helped me to understand the problem!

Comment: @SunyoungKim You are welcome. If you found the answer particularly useful, you could mark it as [your accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Check out the [help page on how to respond to answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), which also mentions accepting answers and discourages using comments to leave 'thank you' notes.

Comment: Oh it was such a huge newbie's mistake! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Your insert logic seems wrong in the last line :

**current.next = newNode;**

**current.next.previous = newNode;**

*This actually means*

**newNode.previous=newNode;**

*Since you are setting the value of current.next to newNode in the 3rd statement*

It should be :

**newNode.next.previous = newNode.**

Comment: hi! Thanks a lot for your help!. I understood pretty much. But I got this error! - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'previous' of null. I have no idea how to deal with this. Still I am so thankful about your well-organized answer! THANKS!!